# How can I upgrade major Kubuntu versions by command line?

Tags: apt, upgrade, kubuntu

The [recommended](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TrustyUpgrades/Kubuntu) way to upgrade Kubuntu versions is using `kubuntu-devel-release-upgrade`, which opens up a GUI window.

Is there a purely command-line method for distribution upgrades?

### Background

When attempting to upgrade using the GUI, it progressed through "Preparing to upgrade", "Setting new software channels" and "Getting new packages", and then stalled on "Installing the upgrades". A window popped up saying:

> Could not install the upgrades. The upgrade has aborted. Your system
>   could be in an unusable state. A recovery will run now (dpkg --configure -a).

I clicked "OK" (or was it "close"?), and the GUI now was stuck at 45%. I could no longer scroll the in-built terminal output, and the GUI window appeared to be stuck.

Looking at the terminal from which I launched `kubuntu-devel-release-upgrade`, I can see

```
Configuration file '/etc/apport/crashdb.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
```

This launch-terminal did not accept input. I killed the GUI process from the launching terminal, then ran `dpkg --configure -a`, which seems to continue where I left off, presenting me again with the above query.

From the GUI, it seemed like there were two more steps: "Cleaning up" and "Restarting the computer". Is the former merely `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`?

I presume that this hang was due to the GUI "Distribution Upgrade" window being unable to accept text input.

**In the future, is there a purely command-line method for distribution upgrades?**

Comment: I see a vote to close, but as I say, this is not a question about the beta specifically. That was just background. This is a generic question about upgrading distributions. It may well have been 13.04 to 13.10.

Comment: Is not being closed because is a beta, but because bugs are off topic. Your upgrade procedure shouldn't get "stuck" and the developers of the helper should be aware of the problem.

Comment: @Braiam Fair call. I edited the question to make it not about the bug part any more.

Comment: Seeing how the (edited) question now asks for a general alternative of the GUI process of upgrading Kubuntu machines I don't think the close votes are warranted any more. I vote to leave this open.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

I used this to upgrade to 14.10, and it worked fine, including allowing me to respond to prompts such as in the question above.

Comment: Well, I'm at 14.04 and it says "No new release found" despite 15.10 being out...

Comment: @SF. Have you got your version numbers correct? It's only June 2015, so 15.10 is *not* out yet. However, I successfully upgraded from 14.04 to 14.10 using this command, as above.

Comment: my mistake, 15.04.

Comment: @SF. I'm not sure. I used this command a few months ago and it upgraded to 15.04 fine. Perhaps try `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` first?

Comment: Is it secure? Do I have to do a backup? Do I have to store my settings KMail etc.?

Comment: @ka3ak This sounds like another question. Possibly two, at least.

Comment: @Sparhawk Yes. But it sounded to brave to me. You do this and that. But whether it is safe... I'm considering whether do it or not.

Comment: @ka3ak Oh, I see what you mean. "Secure" implied "security" from malicious parties to me. Well, I suspect that upgrading from command line is probably exactly what the GUI does as a backend, so it should be identically "safe" as a normal upgrade.